# Prestashop custom bundle product

Tags: php, bundle, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.6

I know there is default bundle pack integrated in the system. But what I want to achieve is like customer will be able to customize those bundle packs like increasing the number of a particular product in the pack. Or even they might exclude any product they want.

In simple words, instead of just showing "3 x Package 1" like in the following picture, I want 3 products list in the cart so that any individual product can be excluded from the pack. Any guidance to achieve my objective will be greatly appreciated.

[image: pack]

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to buy a module, like this: http://addons.prestashop.com/en/1015-advanced-pack-5-create-bundles-of-products.html

If you don't know how to modify prestashop or to create a module it's not so easy to reach your objective :)